# Generate lazy values

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

Related: [Program my microwave oven](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8791/43319). Inspired by [Generate lazy microwave input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73914/43319).

The lazy value of the non-negative integer *N* is the smallest of the integers that are closest to *N* while all their digits are identical.

Return (by any means) the lazy value of a given (by any means) *N*.

*N* ≤ <s>the largest integer that your language represents in non-exponent form by default.</s> 1000000 (A lot of interesting solutions are lost because of this too-high requirement.)

### Test cases:

```
   0 →    0
   8 →    8
   9 →    9
  10 →    9
  16 →   11
  17 →   22
  27 →   22
  28 →   33
 100 →   99
 105 →   99
 106 →  111
 610 →  555
 611 →  666
7221 → 6666
7222 → 7777
```

---

The colleague in question proved that there will be no ties: Except for 9/11, 99/111, etc. for which one is shorter than the other, two consecutive valid answers are always an odd distance apart, so no integer can be exactly equidistant from them.

Answer (score 15):

### JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
n=>~-(n*9+4).toPrecision(1)/9|0
```

Directly computes the lazy value for each `n`.

Edit: Only works up to 277777778 due to the limitations of JavaScript's integer type. Alternative versions:

```
n=>((n*9+4).toPrecision(1)-1)/9>>>0
```

35 bytes, works up to 16666666667.

```
n=>((n=(n*9+4).toPrecision(1))-n[0])/9
```

38 bytes, works up to 944444444444443. But that's still some way short of 2<sup>53</sup> which is 9007199254740992.

Comment: @user81655 I've added some alternative versions with their numeric limitations.

Comment: I couldn't get this algorithm to work with `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` either because `8e16 - 1` is expressed as `8e16`. Sadly, it looks like the only way would be hard-coding the maximum result. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @user81655 I lowered the upper bound to allow the solution.

Comment: Got you to 10k @Neil, love the golfs!

Comment: @NiCkNewman Woohoo! Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain this for those of us unfamiliar with Javascript?

Comment: @ngenisis Because lazy values are of the form k*((10^n)-1)/9, multiplying the original number by 9 should give you a number near to k*10^n. Adding 4 and calling `toPrecision` achieves the necessary rounding. It then remains to regenerate the lazy value given k*10^n.

Answer (score 5):

## Jelly, 16 bytes

```
ḤRµDIASµÐḟµạ³ỤḢị
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikUsK1RElBU8K1w5DhuJ_CteG6ocKz4buk4bii4buL&input=&args=NjEx)

#### How it works

```
ḤRµDIASµÐḟµạ³ỤḢị  Main link. Input: n

Ḥ                 Compute 2n.
 R                Yield [1, ..., 2n] or [0].
  µ               Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: R (range)
   D              Convert to base 10.
    I             Compute all differences of consecutive decimal digits.
     A            Take the absolute values of the differences.
      S           Sum the absolute values.
       µÐḟ        Filter-false by the chain to the left.
          µ       Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: L (lazy integers)
           ạ³     Take the absolute difference of each lazy integer and n (input).
             Ụ    Grade up; sort the indices of L by the absolute differences.
                  This is stable, so ties are broken by earlier occurrence and,
                  therefore, lower value.
              Ḣ   Head; retrieve the first index, corresponding to the lowest
                  absolute difference.
               ị  Retrieve the item of L at that index.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 200 bytes

```
WITH v(i)AS(SELECT 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT DECODE(SIGN(i),0,-1,-1,-i,-i-1)FROM v WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(:1+i,'([0-9])\1+','\1'))>1)SELECT:1+MIN(i)KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY rownum)FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(i) AS
(
  SELECT 0 FROM DUAL      -- Starts with 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DECODE(SIGN(i),0,-1,-1,-i,-i-1) -- Increments i, alternating between negatives and positives
  FROM   v 
  WHERE  LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(:1+i,'([0-9])\1+','\1'))>1  -- Stop when the numbers is composed of only one digit
)
SELECT :1+MIN(i)KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY rownum) FROM v;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 26 bytes

<s>This answer doesn't always return the smallest value in a tie, but that isn't in the specs, so awaiting clarification</s> fixed for 3 bytes.

```
hSh.g.a-kQsmsM*RdjkUTtBl`Q
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hSh.g.a-kQsmsM%2aRdjkUTtBl%60Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=107%0A105%0A104%0A7222%0A7221%0A8&debug=0).

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 25 bytes

```
2*:"@Vt!=?@]]N$vtG-|4#X<)
```

Uses brute force, so it may take a while for large numbers.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mio6IkBWdCE9P0BdXU4kdnRHLXw0I1g8KQ&input=MTA2)

```
2*:       % range [1,2,...,2*N], where is input
"         % for each number in that range
  @V      %   push that number, convert to string
  t!=     %   test all pair-wise combinations of digits for equality
  ?       %   if they are all equal
    @     %     push number: it's a valid candidate
  ]       %   end if
]         % end for each
N$v       % column array of all stack contents, that is, all candidate numbers
t         % duplicate
G-|       % absolute difference of each candidate with respect to input
4#X<      % arg min
)         % index into candidate array to obtain the minimizer. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
haDQsM*M*`MTSl`Q
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=haDQsM*M*%60MTSl%60Q&input=8&test_suite_input=8%0A9%0A10%0A16%0A17%0A27%0A28%0A100%0A105%0A106%0A610%0A611%0A7221%0A7222&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=haDQsM*M*%60MTSl%60Q&input=8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=8%0A9%0A10%0A16%0A17%0A27%0A28%0A100%0A105%0A106%0A610%0A611%0A7221%0A7222&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
haDQsM*M*`MTSl`Q   implicit: Q = input number
              `Q   convert Q to a string
             l     take the length
            S      create the list [1, 2, ..., len(str(Q))]
         `MT       create the list ["0", "1", "2", "3", ..., "9"]
        *          create every combination of these two lists:
                   [[1, "0"], [1, "1"], [1, "2"], ..., [len(str(Q)), "9"]]
      *M           repeat the second char of each pair according to the number:
                   ["0", "1", "2", ..., "9...9"]
    sM             convert each string to a number [0, 1, 2, ..., 9...9]
  D                order these numbers by:
 a Q                  their absolute difference with Q
h                  print the first one
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 32

Based on the beautiful JavaScript solution by Neil.

```
$_=0|1/9*~-sprintf"%.e",$_*9+4.1
```

Starts to fail at `5e15`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 122 bytes

```
f@x_:=Last@Sort[Flatten@Table[y*z,{y,1,9},{z,{FromDigits@Table[1,10~Log~x+1-Log[10,1055555]~Mod~1]}}],Abs[x-#]>Abs[x-#2]&]
```

Function named x.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```js
n=>eval(`for(i=a=0;i<=n;a=i%10?a:++i)p=i,i+=a;n-p>i-n?i:p`)
```

#### Recursive Solution (56 bytes)

This is a bit shorter but does not work for `n > 1111111110` because the maximum call stack size is exceeded, so it is technically invalid.

```js
f=(n,p,a,i=0)=>n<i?n-p>i-n?i:p:f(n,i,(i-=~a)%10?a:i++,i)
```

### Explanation

Iterates through every lazy number until it gets to the first which is greater than `n`, then compares `n` to this and the previous number to determine the result.

```js
var solution =

n=>
  eval(`           // eval enables for loop without {} or return
    for(
      i=a=0;       // initialise i and a to 0
      i<=n;        // loop until i > n, '<=' saves having to declare p above
      a=i%10?a:++i // a = amount to increment i each iteration, if i % 10 == 0 (eg.
    )              //     99 + 11 = 110), increment i and set a to i (both become 111)
      p=i,         // set p before incrementing i
      i+=a;        // add the increment amount to i
    n-p>i-n?i:p    // return the closer value of i or p
  `)
```

```html
N = <input type="number" oninput="R.textContent=solution(+this.value)"><pre id="R"></pre>
```

Comment: I lowered the upper bound to allow your solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
9*U+4 rApUs l¹/9|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@2@pFaptolDkWBBarJBzaKe@ZY3B///mRkZGAA)

<sub>Based on [Neil's technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73944/61613)</sub>

Non-competing [solution](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=KjkrNCBoIC85fDA=&input=NzIyMg==):

```
*9+4 h /9|0
```

Comment: And now you can do `*9+4 h /9|0` :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! I'm having a lot of fun with Japt :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
9Ývy7L×})˜ïD¹-ÄWQÏ{¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASIA3f//OcOddnk3TMOXfSnLnMOvRMK5LcOEV1HDj3vCrP//MTA1)

```
9Ý                   # Push 0..9
  vy7L×})˜           # For each digit, 0-9, push 1-7 copies of that number.
          ïD         # Convert to integers, dupe the list.
            ¹        # Push original input (n).
             -Ä      # Push absolute differences.
               WQ    # Get min, push 1 for min indices.
                 Ï{¬ # Push indices from original array that are the min, sort, take first.
```

Comment: 99 is surely more lazy than 111, as it only requires two button presses.

Comment: @Adám fair enough, added head command.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
Min@Nearest[##&@@@Table[d(10^n-1)/9,{n,0,6},{d,0,9}],#]&
```

Pure function with first argument `#`, works for inputs up to `10^6`.

For a nonnegative integer `n` and a digit `d`, `10^n-1 = 99...9` (`9` repeated `n` times), so `d(10^n-1)/9 = dd...d` (`d` repeated `n` times). Creates a `Table` of values for `0 <= n <= 6` and `0 <= d <= 9`, then flattens the table, finds the list of elements `Nearest` to `#` and takes the `Min`.

I believe this version will work for arbitrarily large integers:

```
Min@Nearest[##&@@@Table[d(10^n-1)/9,{n,0,IntegerLength@#},{d,0,9}],#]&
```